# Alto word coordinates viewer

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, canvas

I have a task where I need to convert omnipage XML to alto XML format. So far I'm done with the XML conversion, I'm in the part of checking if the converted XML falls in the proper coordinates. I tried a software call aletheia (http://www.primaresearch.org/tools/) and the coordinates fall in its proper places. But I want to do the same in my WPF application.

But my coordinates are wrong (I used the input that i used in aletheia software).

Here is the output:

[image]

and here is my code

this is my code for getting the coordinates from XML file

```
public class Rect
        {
            public double Width { get; set; }
            public double Height { get; set; }
            public double Left { get; set; }
            public double Top { get; set; }
            public SolidColorBrush Color { get; set; }
            public string textBlockID {get; set;}
        }
     private void ReadAlto(string filename)
            {
                try
                {
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
                    foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("TextBlock").ToList())
                    {
                        double l = 0, t = 0, width = 0, height = 0;
                        l = double.Parse(item.Attribute("HPOS").Value);
                        t = double.Parse(item.Attribute("VPOS").Value);
                        width = double.Parse(item.Attribute("WIDTH").Value);
                        height = double.Parse(item.Attribute("HEIGHT").Value);
                        string id = item.Attribute("ID").Value;

                        Console.WriteLine("L: " + l + " T: " + t + " Width: " + width + " Height: " + height);
                        if (l!=0 &&  t !=0 &&  width != 0 && height !=0)
                        {

                            rects.Add(new Rect()
                            {
                                Width = width,
                                Height = height,
                                Left = l,
                                Top = t,
                                Color = Brushes.Red,
                                textBlockID = id
                            });
                        }

                    }

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
                }
            }
```

and here is my code for drawing in the canvas

```
foreach (Rect rect in rects)
                {
                    // ... Create Rectangle object.
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                    r.Width = rect.Width;
                    r.Height = rect.Height;
                    r.Fill = rect.Color;

                    // ... Set canvas position based on Rect object.
                    Canvas.SetLeft(r, rect.Left);
                    Canvas.SetTop(r, rect.Top);

                    // ... Add to canvas.
                    canvas.Children.Add(r);
                }
```

Comment: Are you sure the original is scaled 1:1? Maybe it's stretched or otherwise scaled to fit?

Comment: how can i check that? i need to set the width of the image and canvas equal to each other right?

Comment: Check /alto/Description/MeasurementUnit in the XML.  It may be one of mm10 (1/10th of a millimeter), inch1200 (1/1200th of an inch) or pixel